# How to display the data in listview from database and CursorAdapter by using search function

Tags: android, listview, search, cursor

i hava listview in my app and i add EditView i need to search in database and CursorAdapter

how can get The result from search?

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);   
Cursor cursor = db.readData();  

String[] from = new String[] {  DatabaseHandler.KEY_COED ,DatabaseHandler.KEY_Quantity};          
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.Code ,R.id.Quantity};  

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Show.this, R.layout.view_code, cursor, from, to);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This code is just for displaying the data in a listview.

Answer (score 0):

To implement search, I use a custom Adapter. The implementation of the custom adapter really depends on your situation. To start with, is it an adaptive search? Like do you want a TextWatcher on the EditText so that results are filtered as the user types?

Also, do you need to perform DB updates or do you need to have an open `Cursor` during your interaction with the ListView. If not, you can create a custom ArrayList class and use the search data to filter the result list. If so, then you need a custom Cursor that will re-query the database using your search criteria.

Regardless, here is a reference for Custom ArrayAdapter:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

And custom CursorAdapter:

http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/

Also, keep this in mind. Your custom adapter will need methods for updating/clearing your search. And in the "getView" or "newView" methods, you can dynamically skip or ignore elements of your cursor or array to only display the ones you want.

You may also want to build a custom ArrayList object that holds each row of data and then build your search methods and filtering on it.

It might also be useful to add a custom comparator to the ArrayList (which is what I ultimately ended up doing to get the results to display correctly depending on search options, etc.). For example, doing a search for a name, you may want to search the list several times for last, then first, then middle - and then you may want to display the results in a different order (like by last name, where a middle name result should be placed first).